# Crow has to drop additional $320$ or $400$ volume pebbles to raise the water of the tank to drink?

Tags: arithmetic, volume

> A small treat is floating in a rectangular tank measuring 8 inches wide, 10 inches long, and 12 inches high. If the water is currently 5 inches high and a smart crow can reach at most 3 inches down into the tank, at least how many $2 \times 2 \times 2$-inch metal cubes should the crow drop in the tank to get the treat?

Solution A:
I assume the tank has a volume of $5 \cdot 8 \cdot 10.$
The crow can reach three inches, so that amounts to a volume of $8 \cdot 8 \cdot 10.$
The total volume is $12 \cdot 8 \cdot 10,$ and I need to add $400 \ \text{in}^3=12\cdot 8 \cdot 10 - 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \ \text{in}^3.$

Meaning: 50 of $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 $ cubes.

---

Solution B:

The height difference: $12-5-3=4$ inches.

To fill $ 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 10$, or $320$ volume, so drop $40$ cubes.

Comment: Solution B is correct. How do you get from $12\cdot 8 \cdot 10$ to $400$?

Comment: Both solutions are correct if I followed your thoughtprocess correctly. $12\times8\times10-8\times8\times10=320$ not $400$. By the way, the community appreciates your efforts to format in mathjax.

Comment: In which book does your intructor find such hilarious "real life problems" ?